# Third party type messing with my proptypes?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-tsx, react-typescript

I'm working with the formik library currenty and have props for my React.FC defined as the following:

```
import { useField, FieldAttributes } from "formik";

const propTypes = {
  label: PropTypes.string
};

type TextFieldProps = InferProps<typeof propTypes> & FieldAttributes<[]>;
```

however when I try to assign proptypes to my component:

```
TextField.propTypes = propTypes;
```

I get an error that is quite hard to understand, but it seems like the "FieldAttributes" type is screwing it up somehow, how can I account for it in my proptypes?

```
Type '{ label: PropTypes.Requireable<string>; }' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap<InferPropsInner<Pick<{ label: Requireable<string>; }, never>> & Partial<InferPropsInner<Pick<{ label: Requireable<string>; }, "label">>> & ... 4 more ... & { ...; }> | WeakValidationMap<...> | WeakValidationMap<...> | undefined'.
  Type '{ label: PropTypes.Requireable<string>; }' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap<InferPropsInner<Pick<{ label: Requireable<string>; }, never>> & Partial<InferPropsInner<Pick<{ label: Requireable<string>; }, "label">>> & ... 4 more ... & { ...; }>'.
    The types returned by 'toString(...)' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Error | null'.ts(2322)
```

And the TextField FC:

```
export const TextField: React.FC<TextFieldProps> = ({ label, ...props }) => {
  const [field, meta] = useField(props);
  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <label htmlFor={field.name}>
        {label}
        <input
          {...field}
          {...meta}
          className="form-control"
          placeholder={placeholder}
        />
      </label>
      <div>{meta.error}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: Where is `TextField` declared? You showed us `TextFieldProps`, which isn't a class so it doesn't have a prototype or constructor that can have properties assigned to it.

Comment: @kaya3 Updated post